# Failed to update app for game center entitlement key

Tags: xcode, app-store, app-store-connect, game-center

The app has been running for years, with Game Center enabled.

Yesterday I uploaded new version to AppStore connect, and clicked "Add to review", but Apple rejected to review and gave a warning "You must add the com.apple.developer.game-center key in Xcode."

I followed the instruction and checked the entitlement has been added

[image]

And also an entitlement file was created by Xcode

[image]

Then I uploaded a new build to AppStore connect and submit it to be reviewed again, STILL, the app review was rejected again.

I also tried to add that key to file info.plist, nothing works.

Hope some can help to solve this?

Comment: Make sure to perform the same checks on your other Xcode targets, especially if you happen to have Apple Watch support in the project - they will also need the Game Center entitlement.

Comment: The app has only one target inside, and it manages signing automatically.

Comment: What you posted looks good from Xcode side, all I can suggest for further troubleshooting is:
• In App Store Connect -> go to the selected build -> Build metadata and validate that the entitlement is indeed listed
• In dev portal, validate that the explicit App Identifier has the checkbox checked for Game Center (I assume it is)
• In dev portal, go through all App IDs in case there is a leftover identifier related to your app

Comment: Emmm, there is no Game center entitlement listed in AppStore connect build metadata. It's weird thing that I've followed Apple's instruction and double check that Game Center is enabled in Xcode, but AppStore connect fails to read it out.

Comment: Then it's likely something in the export/distribution process. Is the entitlement listed in the last step of the export dialog, before uploading build to App Store Connect?

Comment: Found a solution online, disable `Automatically manage signing` and use a dowloaded profile, it works. Thanks for your help.